# RHEL: 4 Cores available but only 1 used

Tags: redhat, java, central-processing-unit, multi-core

I'm running a heavy java process on my rhel. It had 8GB of RAM and 1 core for CPU. With the help `top` and `htop` I saw there was not enough CPU available for this process.

I added 3 extra cores in VMware and rebooted. If I execute `nproc` I see 4 so there are now 4 cores on the server.

I restart the java process but it's not going faster. I read that top could show till 400% if you have 4 cores. (each core till 100%). When I execute `top` I see 100%. I suspect one core is in full use and the 3 other ones aren't doing anything.

Is there a way to let this process or my server use all the cores available? I'm on a `RHEL 7.2`

Comment: Your Java application has to use parallel algorithms and multiple threads to make use of multiple cores. How did you find out it needs more cores?

Comment: @eckes I use subgit (https://subgit.com/) as application. I saw with htop it reached it max CPU so I thought increasing the number of cores was a good idea.

Comment: Congratulations, you've just discovered why two 1GHz processors aren't functionally equivalent to a 2GHz processor.  Parallelisation is not trivial for most tasks.

Comment: But there is even no single difference. That's also normal?

Comment: You might be able to have faster GC pauses or use CMS to background garbage collect. Or you run multiple Repository conversions in parallel. This was it can use more that one core.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your JVMs to make use of multiple processors, as others have mentioned in the comments. This is an application issue, not an OS issue. I'm fairly certain the default is only to use one CPU. If you don't configure it specifically to use more, you will peg one CPU at 100% while the other three go nearly unused and your app suffers.